# Check box within drop down list in rails association models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, drop-down-menu, associations

I want check boxes in my drop down list using simple form gem, i am getting a list with association,

```
<%= f.association :vendors %>
```

In the **html.erb** simple form can show me the all vendors for above code, and all i need to put check box on each vendor so that i can select vendors as i wish,
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should mention that you're using simple form gem, and checking the [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations) would be helpful

```
<%= f.association :vendors, as: :check_boxes %>
```